# Javascript Node Request How To Send GET Variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, get, request

I see that the `request` package is the standard for making HTTP API requests with NodeJS. I need to use it to send some requests but in [the docs](https://github.com/request/request) and all the examples I find, I don't see how to pass GET variables. I only see how to pass POST params. Here's my code:

```
request.get("https://api.example.com", function (err, res, body) {
        if (!err) {
            var resultsObj = JSON.parse(body);
            //Just an example of how to access properties:
            console.log(resultsObj.MRData);
        }
    });
```

Where to set the GET? I don't like doing it in the URL.

Comment: GET parameters _are_ part of the URL, so why would you want to put them anywhere else?

Comment: GET variables are usually standard to be encoded *in the url itself*, you're not supposed to pass 'body' data in the same way as a POST request. Send them as a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `qs` property. From the docs:

> qs - object containing querystring values to be appended to the uri

```
request({
  qs: {
   foo: 'bar',
  },
  uri: 'http://foo.bar/'
}, callback)
```

Comment: Ahh. Not a very common name for it. Thanks.

Comment: @xendi — It is a very common name for it, and also the one used in the various web standards.

Comment: I know it's technically around in docs but usually you just read people say "Get request/variables." It's been quite a while since I read querystring. Maybe it's just me.